# Why Chrome, FF, Safari, Android ICS(and above version) do not display object movie flash?

Tags: flash, browser, movie

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0">
   <PARAM NAME="FlashVars" VALUE="file=2.flv&amp;autostart=true">
   <PARAM NAME="Movie" VALUE="player.swf">
</object>
```

Above HTML(should be modified the url) is played at IE, Android GB. 
But at other browsers like FF, Safari and Chrome, it is not played. 
Especially at Android ICS it is not played.

**Is there anyone who knows that the reason why other browsers can display the flash movie specially at Android ICS?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: No `embed` tag? Chrome and FF need an embed.

Comment: Do you know why webkit based browses do not display above HTML?

Answer (score 0):

[Flash is no longer officially supported on Android](http://www.readwriteweb.com/mobile/2012/08/adobe-flash-on-android-rip.php). If an ICS device doesn't have it already, obtaining it is not trivial.